# Is there any way to making transition without storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift3

I tried making transition animation for changing between two viewController. Is there any way to make that without using storyboard?

This code for calling new viewController (which I didn't use storyboard):

```
 @objc func handleAccount() {
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userButtonLauncher())
    navController.transitioningDelegate = self
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And this codes for transition:

```
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.transitionMode = .present
    transition.startingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    return transition
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.transitionMode = .pop
    transition.startingPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    return transition
}
```

Comment: try searching `push viewController programmatically`

Comment: Hi Lu, I already tried push viewController but I think transition page cover viewController. When I wrote                                                                                'let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userButtonLauncher())
        navController.transitioningDelegate = self
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)' . UserButtonLauncher under the transition page. I see only blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. I just add that code for calling animation transition in my homecontroller:

```
extension HomeController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return faceanim()

}
func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return faceanim()

}
```

}

And to button action is:

```
    @objc func handleAccount() {

    let userConVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: userButtonLauncher())
    userConVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.present(userConVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Please, mark this as resolved so others can quickly find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can! It depends on what you would like to do, so if you need to use the defaults animation on code without using storyboard you can just:
instantiate your ViewController, set the animation you want and open the ViewController

`let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc_id") 
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Otherwise you can create your custom transition, see this easy guide:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/322-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started

Comment: Thanks for answer Marcoc. I'm new in swift I tried a lot of thing to do that but I can't find any way. If I ask more clearly I write CircularTransition.swift but I didn't use segue so I call second viewController with navigationController code but transitionDelegate and modalTransitionStyle codes cover my second controller I think. I don't know did I explain properly ?

Comment: No problem! I suggest you to update your question with some code of your project, so it's easier to help you. Anyway try to comment the transitionDelegate line and see if it still covered or not please

Comment: I tried to edit my question. I hope I will explain my question more clearly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: thank you! from where do you call handleAccount ?  from the transition class?

Comment: Actually I can't call handleAccount in my transition class because I created circle as UIView(). I can't find way to call that function in transition class. Is there any way to call?

Comment: Did you try to comment the transitioningDelegate line?